# Samsung M31S screen is frozen at startup, it boots up but the screen stays frozen until sleep or power button press

Tags: samsung, boot, screen

The phone was used for 2 months and the front glass got cracked but its really not that noticeable.
After 6 months of use the phone died while using it.
It was dead but after ODIN stock flash the phone boots up but the screen is frozen at the first logo SAMSUNG M31S powered by android even though the phone boots up to the system and I can see the screen via Vysor app on my computer.(used talkback to finish samsung setup google sign up etc, enabled usb debugging and I was able to use Vysor to see the phone's screen. When the screen goes to sleep or I press the lock/power button the screen goes black but it won't come back if button is pressed again(talkback says the screen off screen on when pressing power button but the display doesn't' respond, I have to force restart it and its the same issue all over again stuck screen on logo but works just fine touch too.
After the bootloader was unlocked the phone's screen is stuck at the "your device' bootloader is unlocked.... presss power button to continue)it boots just fine but screen is stuck there!(if I lock the bootloader the screen would get stuck at first samsung M31S powered by android screen instead.
Download and recovery modes work just fine and they are displayed correctly but booting to system  just frozen screen at startup and fully functional phone(calls, touch wifi everything)
I tried flashing stock firmware multiple times with nand erase and re partitioning doesn't help.

I was able to install twrp recovery(unlocked the bootloader OEM unlock...) and it does work. But no custom roms exist for this device yet, so I can't try those.
The only thing that I noticed is in stock recovery logs there is one error unable to set property ro.boot time.init.mount.cache "5" try count 3(I've seen different numbers there its not always the same number in " ".
I cannot flash factory binary I get FAIL please get approval to use factory binary. The phone is on latest U3 Android 11.

Let me know what could cause screen to freeze and system to boot up just fine and screen to work just fine in recovery stock twrp and download mode.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130679/discussion-on-question-by-serifpersia-samsung-m31s-screen-is-frozen-at-startup).